# How to convert columns of dataframe based on best-fit types of values in them?

Tags: python, pandas

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-column-type-in-pandas) (number 4) I am trying to use `df.convert_dtypes()`

Pandas version: 0.25.3

Reproducible:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    "int": np.zeros((5, ), dtype=np.int),
    "float": np.zeros((5, ), dtype=np.float),
    "string": ["a", "b", "c", "ddd", "FFFFF"],
    "bool": [True, False, True, True, False]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

output so far:

> ```
>    int  float string   bool
> 0    0    0.0      a   True
> 1    0    0.0      b  False
> 2    0    0.0      c   True
> 3    0    0.0    ddd   True
> 4    0    0.0  FFFFF  False
> int         int32
> float     float64
> string     object
> bool         bool
> dtype: object
> ```

```
df.convert_dtypes()
print(df.dtypes)
```

I would expect the trivial types, rather than `object`, but getting

> `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'convert_dtypes'`

What's the way to do this?

Comment: what version of pandas are you using?

Comment: Need pandas `1.+`, for me working nice.

Comment: well, looks like i am way behind wow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip install --upgrade pandas`

Thanks to @jezrael need version `1.+`